# SQL Query to Count Distinct with Group By with a Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are a number of locations with members at different steps in an ordinal process. The members can be in multiple processes with different progress at one or more locations.

The join table between locations and members could look something like this called steps.

```
| id | member_id | step_no | location_id | process_id |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1         | 2       | 10          | 57
| 2  | 1         | 5       | 10          | 58
| 3  | 2         | 5       | 11          | 37
| 4  | 2         | 1       | 10          | 57
```

I have not been able to figure how to get a unique count of members, by location, for the furthest step the member is in the process.

```
location_id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
---------------------------------
 10         | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
 11         | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

So far, I have this query:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT m.id), l.id, l.name
      FROM members m
      INNER JOIN steps s ON m.id = s.member_id
      INNER JOIN locations l ON s.location_id = l.id
      WHERE step_no = 5
      GROUP BY l.id
      ORDER BY l.name
```

But this only returns step_no = 5, of course, and if I wrote five of these queries, the member could be counted twice at different steps.

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called *pivot table*. I have no idea how to get one in postgresql, but you should search that term. Maybe you'll figure it out.

Comment: Please define 'furthest' step (per member) - highest id, highest step number, latest timestamp?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Good question. What I meant by "furthest" is the highest step number for a particular member at each location. For example, member 2 above appears at two locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
location_id
,sum(case when max_step = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as step_one_cnt
,sum(case when max_step = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as step_two_cnt
,sum(case when max_step = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as step_three_cnt
,sum(case when max_step = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as step_four_cnt
,sum(case when max_step = 5 then 1 else 0 end) as step_five_cnt
FROM
(select
s.location_id, 
s.member_id, 
max(s.step_no) as max_step
FROM steps S
group by 1,2
) as base
group by 1
```

Breaking it down, the base query gives you the following result:

```
member_id |  location_id | max_step_no
-------------------------------------------------------

| 1         | 10       | 5 
| 2         | 10       | 1
| 2         | 11       | 5
```

The aggregation query on this subquery (base), basically pivots the result into the form you would like to see it. The only limitation of this approach is that the number of steps is statically defined in advanced.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution. I will have to verify a little more. Right now it only returns counts at step 5. The statically defined steps is not a downside to me.

Comment: Please don't group by column ordinals - please always explicitly list the column names.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Interesting, what is the reason behind that ? The reason I prefer ordinals is due to the way grouping is done in the rdbms I usually work with, making it more convenient. For example:

sel sum(test_column) as test_column from test_table group by 1 

This groups by the selected column. On the other hand:

sel sum(test_column) as test_column from test_table group by test_column

This groups by the table column, rather than the alias column

Comment: That's probably because the `SELECT` clause is getting evaluated _after_ the `GROUP BY` clause, so the alias doesn't exist yet (this depends somewhat on DB - this also usually effects `HAVING` clauses).  That's actually a dangerous semantic difference - you are getting different answers, right?  Regardless, it's a good way to make your intentions clearer (especially if the order is something other than `1, 2`...) - and not all RDBMSs support this syntax, anyways.  It also doesn't work in all situations - what about grouping by a column not returned in the query?

Comment: That reasoning is correct. However, in case of our architecture/coding standards,we don't want to highlight the semantic difference when providing access between different data layers e.g coalesce(value, default_value) as value; the benefit of this comes in simplifying process automation eg. using generators more easily to create data transformation processes (e.g history handling of data), oand automated testing scripts. This can of course be done by maintaining a mapping between the source and target name mappings; but it adds overhead to the automation process.

Comment: This is easier to maintain when used with other standards so that we don't run into issues  and prevents the above mentioned grouping 'bug' in case it happens.  (1) build select list so grouping order moves sequentially with an increment of 1...n without including aggregate functions in the grouping, which are added in the select list from n+1. (2) Any changes to the grouping order from (1)  are implemented as part of qualify/partition clause, where it is explicitly marked, making a 'different grouping than the select list columns' more granular /easier-to-spot, than the group by case. (3)

Comment: If aggregate function needs to be grouped further, this has to be done in an outer query.

This may not work in every case/architecture/platform of course, but it has its advantages (especially with code generation/automation and transparency, and works for us :) 

PS:I wasn't aware of the syntax being not supported in other RDBMs.

Answer (score 0):

1- First select the following into a temp table:

```
select   location_id , step_no , count(member_id) as count 
into     stepsPrime
from     (select member_id, location_id, max(step_no) as step_no
          from steps 
          group by member_id, location_id ) definedTab 
group by location_id, step_no 
order by location_id;
```

2- Use the following query to pivot the above results:

```
select distinct stp.location_id,
       stp1.count as step1, 
       stp2.count as step2, 
       stp3.count as step3, 
       stp4.count as step4, 
       stp5.count as step5 
from stepsPrime stp 
left join stepsPrime stp1 on stp.location_id = stp1.location_id and stp1.step_no = 1 
left join stepsPrime stp2 on stp.location_id = stp2.location_id and stp2.step_no = 2 
left join stepsPrime stp3 on stp.location_id = stp3.location_id and stp3.step_no = 3 
left join stepsPrime stp4 on stp.location_id = stp4.location_id and stp4.step_no = 4 
left join stepsPrime stp5 on stp.location_id = stp5.location_id and stp5.step_no = 5;
```

Comment: Sorry, two things - 1) I believe postgreSQL supports CTEs, so you shouldn't need an explicit temp table, and 2) You're going to be counting users at _every_ step they've taken, essentially counting them twice (or more!) which the OP was explicitly hoping to avoid.  You need to add OLAP functions for something like this to work...

Comment: Can you give more detail about how to count the user-step?

Comment: @AmyA Hi, thanks for your answer. To count the member step, I would like to get the highest step number for each location. In other words, if the member has multiple steps at the same locations (member_id 10 above) take the highest. If member has steps at multiple locations, count the highest at each location.